# How to fix "A value is required but not present in the request" exception?

Tags: c#

I have a textbox, and it was designed to not accept an empty value. Means, I cannot save the form without a value in the textbox. 
But now, I want to save it without a value. How to do that?
A method is called to check the value/if duplicate, that is-

```
  public bool CheckBcodeExists(string barcode)
        {
            string qry = string.Format("SELECT 1 as EXIST FROM INVHITEM WHERE UPPER(ICODE) = '{0}' OR UPPER(BARCODE) = '{1}'", barcode.ToUpper(), barcode.ToUpper());
            var result = _sqlexecutor.CreateSQLQuery(qry).DynamicList().FirstOrDefault();
            if (result == null)
                return false;

            string exist = Convert.ToString(result.EXIST);

            if (exist != "1")
                return false;

            return true;
        }
```

Mapping of entity is

```
Map(x => x.Barcode).Column("BARCODE").Unique();
```

please guide me how to fix it

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to pass parameters to a database. Instead use parameterized queries. You're vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: Post the *actual* exception, including its call stack. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Right now one can't say if the error was caused due to SQL injection (what if `barcode` contained a `'` ?) or some other code

Comment: What is `_sqlexecutor` and what does `CreateSQLQuery` do? If you're using an ORM why use string concatenation?

Comment: Finally, string comparisons in SQL are typcially case *in*sensitive. This is controlled by the field's collation. This matters - applying `UPPER` to a field means the server can't use any indexes on it and has to scan the entire table. You should probably change the collation of that field to a case-*in*sensitive collation. Which brings us to "Which database are you using"?

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `qry`?

Comment: More to consider: if you want to ensure that there is only one, so never a duplicate, this is a database task. Make this column `UNIQUE` and handle the exception that is raised if the unique constraint is violated. Don't ask the database if there is already one. That is inefficient because you need another query and it's also not safe, it's a race condition

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two questions.

1. How to fix “A value is required but not present in the request” exception?
2. How to allow null/empty values

For 1. You must check if the parameter has any values.
something like this.

```
public bool CheckBcodeExists(string barcode)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcode)) return false; // that'll fix your error and probably also fix your 2nd question. allowing empty values.
```

like everyone else said, use parameterised queries to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: Well , this approach doesn't ensure that there is only one empty barcode in the database. It just says that there is no empty barcode even if there is one.

Comment: you probably will have to include the call stack for further help.